# Script generated by Update-Database has syntax errors while a normal Update-Database works correctly

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 project with using Entity Framework 6.2.0 with many migrations. My problem is, when I remove my database from my local computer and run `Update-Database` the database is created successfully, but when I run `Update-Database -Script` command and save my SQL script and then run the SQL script with

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile ".\build\artifacts\migration.sql" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"
```

I get many syntax errors, such as

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query
> batch.
>
> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Why do I get these errors? And *how* can I resolve them? Why does a normal `update-database` work correctly, but the SQL script has syntax errors?

I think [adding 'GO' statements to Entity Framework migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40598596/1539100) with some modification can resolve my problem.

Comment: @Larnu My problem is this script generate automatically with `Update-Database -Script` but generated script has many many syntax error. I cannot resolve one by one

Comment: Most likely `sqlcmd` is running some statements prior to the script, but not starting a new batch. Most like adding `SET ANSI_NULLS ON;\r\nGO\r\nSET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;\r\nGO\r\n` (where `\r\n` represents a carriage return and line break) at the start of your script will fix the problem. Without the contents of `.\build\artifacts\migration.sql` this is difficult to suggest much more though.

Comment: Ok I read https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34661 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/54765112/1539100 , How to say Update-Database to add GO in scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know and as you can see [SQL Server - Must be first statement in query batch - what and why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34661/229432)

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502(v=sql.105).aspx

> **Rules for Using Batches**
>
> The following rules apply to using batches:
>
> - CREATE DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE RULE, CREATE
>   SCHEMA, CREATE TRIGGER, and CREATE VIEW statements cannot be combined
>   with other statements in a batch. The CREATE statement must start the
>   batch. All other statements that follow in that batch will be
>   interpreted as part of the definition of the first CREATE statement.
> - A table cannot be changed and then the new columns referenced in the
>   same batch.
> - If an EXECUTE statement is the first statement in a batch,
>   the EXECUTE keyword is not required. The EXECUTE keyword is required
>   if the EXECUTE statement is not the first statement in the batch.

The problem is when we generate script instead of using `Update-Database` directly, all of migration want to be run in batching and cause some error when we have some handmade SQL Script in migrations that violate SQL rules.

So to resolve this problem we have to add `/**/ GO` in begin of statements. ( thanks to [Ivan Stus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59471219/1539100) )

Thanks to [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) to help me to investigate the problem.